# Android delay when show data after hide alerdialog loading

Tags: android, retrofit, delay, loading, android-alertdialog

I am using retrofit2 on android. But I've realized that I have a little problem.

I do the following to make calls:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate() {
    super.onStart();

    if(pDialog == null) {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    }
    pDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.loading_dialog));
    pDialog.show();
    setEmptyData();

    ApiInterface apiService = SingletonRetrofit.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<MyResponse<User>> call = apiService.getUserJID(jid_contact_title);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<MyResponse<User>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MyResponse<User>> call, retrofit2.Response<MyResponse<User>> response) {


            if(response.body() != null) {
                 User userdatos = response.body().getData();


                if (response.code() == 200) {

                    nombre = userdatos.getNombre();
                    pais = userdatos.getPais();
                    telefono = userdatos.getTelefono();
                    url_foto = userdatos.getUrl_foto();
                    setData();


                } else {
                    showErrorMessage();
                    setEmptyData();
                }
            }else{
                showErrorMessage();
                setEmptyData();
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MyResponse<User>>call, Throwable t) {
            // Log error here since request failed
            Log.e(TAG, "error a la M");
            Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
        }
    });


}

 private void setData(){

    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.idtextusuario)).setText("casa");
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.idtextpais)).setText("prueba");
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.idtexttelefono)).setText("bien");


   // ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url_foto, (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.idimagecontact)); // Get singleton instance

    pDialog.hide();

}
```

Everything works fine, but I have a little delay I do not like to show the API response.

When you start the activity appears "loading", all ok. But when the loading is hidden there is a small time data not shown, appearing suddenly after a few ms.

Can I fix it?

thanks

Comment: side note (not related) , pass `userdatos` to `setData()` instead of creating `String` fields in the Fragment/Activity.

Comment: oki, yes. This is not my original code, is a rapid test to explain my problem.